# What is the proper way to handle "Permission Denied" when a Firestore document does not exist

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have written rules for Firestore, however, when a document does not exist it throws a "Missing or Insufficient Permissions error". For example

```
firebase.firestore().collection('shipments').doc(order_doc_id)
.onSnapshot(fsResponse => {
...
)}
```

throws the "Missing or Insufficient Permissions error" when `order_doc_id` does not exist.

Here is my security rule for the 'shipments' collection:

```
allow read: if request.auth != null && (resource.data.book_data.seller_id == request.auth.uid || resource.data.buyer_id == request.auth.uid)
```

**Ideally** I would like for it to resolve successfully with `fsResponse.exists === false` and then show the user a "not-found" screen, but this is not the case and the error says nothing about the existence of the document.

What is the proper way to handle this case?

Comment: You should normally not get a "Missing or Insufficient Permissions error", even if the doc does not exist. Are you sure there isn't any side effect from another setting? (Security rules, ...)

Comment: Here is my security rule for the 'shipments' collection ```allow read: if request.auth != null && (resource.data.book_data.seller_id == request.auth.uid || resource.data.buyer_id == request.auth.uid)```

Comment: @RenaudTarnec So technically the ```resource.data.book_data.seller_id == request.auth.uid``` cannot be true if the doc does not exist but I would still like to know if it doesn't exist instead of getting permission denied error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer builds on [@RenaudTarnec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3371862/renaud-tarnec)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67059632/3068190).

The reason your current rules fail, is because they throw an error when used on a non-existent document. Any rule that throws an error is treated as if the rule blocked access.

Your current read rule:

```
allow read: if request.auth != null
            && (resource.data.book_data.seller_id == request.auth.uid
               || resource.data.buyer_id == request.auth.uid);
```

For a document that exists, the rule allows read access if the accessing user is the seller or buyer. But when the document doesn't exist, `resource` will be `null` - this leads to syntax error where you try to read the property `data` on a `null` object - blocking the read. You can see this behaviour in action when testing your rules in the [Rules Playground](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/_/rules) on the Firebase Console.

To allow reads of a non-existant document, you would need to add a `null`-check for `resource`. To prevent abuse, you will probably still want to require a user to be logged in.

```
allow read: if request.auth != null
            && (resource == null
               || resource.data.book_data.seller_id == request.auth.uid
               || resource.data.buyer_id == request.auth.uid);
```

Comment: This works but I'm now getting the  "OK" response in a similar situation even though  the doc doesn't exist.  I would assume that a read query on a doc that doesn't exist should return the "NOT_FOUND" response.

Comment: @Billakosama Security rules language concerns securing suitable access to data. As Firebase is a serverless platform, it is up to the application to define behaviour in the case of data that does not exist by looking for `fsSnapshot.empty()` or `fsSnapshot.exists()` (as appropriate) and handling that case. As one use case of this behaviour, you might be waiting for the document to be created  and returning "NOT_FOUND" when attaching the listener would prevent that from working. For a more traditional RESTful API, abstract it with a server between the application and Cloud Firestore.

Comment: This is exactly my case and I ended up doing as you described, it's just weird that google would include "NOT_FOUND" as a possible response then. Is there any case where this response is ever used?

Comment: @Billakosama gRPC response codes are common across various Google services and were devised so that each service and SDK didn't have to implement their own codes nor rely on HTTP Status Codes. I'm not familiar with what Cloud Firestore specific endpoints return what error codes, but the SDK itself does use `NOT_FOUND` when you try to use `startAt` or `endAt` with documents that do not exist. gRPC codes are also available for custom code in your [Callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.https.md#httpsfunctionserrorcode).

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments, your problem is as follows:

The security rule for the `shipments` collection is

```
allow read: if request.auth != null && (resource.data.book_data.seller_id == request.auth.uid || resource.data.buyer_id == request.auth.uid)
```

therefore `resource.data.book_data.seller_id == request.auth.uid` **cannot be true if the doc does not exist**

and therefore the rule throws the "Missing or Insufficient Permissions error" when I set a listener on the non-existing document.

**HOWEVER**,

> I would still like to know if it doesn't exist instead of getting
> permission denied error

---

The following security rule, using [`!exists`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.exists) to check if the document DOES NOT exist, should do the trick:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /shipments/{shipmentId} {
      allow read: if (
        (!exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/shipments/shipmentId))
        || (request.auth != null && (resource.data.book_data.seller_id == request.auth.uid || resource.data.buyer_id == request.auth.uid))
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `!exists(currentPath)` which incurs a database read, couldn't you just use `resource == null`?

Comment: This works! I adjusted it to use ```resource == null``` as @samthecodingman suggested. Thanks a TON to you both.

Comment: Better approach @samthecodingman, you should add an answer and it should be the accepted one.